# Load navbar from external HTML and set current anchor class to active

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to load a navigation bar from an external HTML file, and automatically set an anchor's tag class to "active" based on the current page.

Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main</title>

    <style>
        .active {
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(loadAndSet());

        function loadAndSet() {
            loadBar();
            setActive();
        }

        function loadBar() {
            $('#bar').load('navigation.html');
        }

        function setActive() {
            var aObjects = document.getElementById("bar").getElementsByTagName("a");

            for (var i = 0; i < aObjects.length; i++) {
                if (document.location.href.indexOf(aObjects[i].href) >= 0) {
                    aObjects[i].className = "active";
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <h1>Content Title</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And here's navigation.html:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:

New code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Main</title>

    <style>
        .active {
            background-color: green;
        }
    </style>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(loadBar());

        function loadBar() {
            $('#bar').load('navigation.html', setActive);
        }

        function setActive() {
            $("#home").addClass("active");
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="bar"></div>
    <h1>Content Title</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And navigation.html:

```
<ul>
<li><a id="home" href="index.html">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="page2" href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
</ul>
```

The navigation bar doesn't even load...

Comment: This is what you are looking for: $(document).ready(loadBar); Just pass the function loadBar, don't execute it. In your code you are executing loadBar immediately and then you pass its return value, which is 'unedefined'.

Answer (score 3):

Your navigation.html code is missing the closing ul-Tag: change the last `<ul>` to `</ul>`.

The second problem is a little bit more difficulty. The page index.html can have multiple different values in `document.location.href`!

It can be:

`http://www.stackoverflow.com/index.html`

or

`http://www.stackoverflow.com/`

or even

`http://www.stackoverflow.com`

Your code wouldn't work for the last two versions of the url.

The third problem is, that the load() function can take a few seconds, so that the code isn't loaded at the time your setActive() is executed. You have to wait until load is finished. You can achieve this by using a callback function:

```
$(document).ready(loadBar());

function loadBar() {
    $('#bar').load('navigation.html', setActive);
}

function setActive() {
    var aObjects = document.getElementById("bar").getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (var i = 0; i < aObjects.length; i++) {
        if (document.location.href.indexOf(aObjects[i].href) >= 0) {
            aObjects[i].className = "active";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the code, but it still doesn't work. The navigation bar just doesn't load for some reason. I'm manually going to index.html.

Comment: Can you check the developer tools in your browser for any JavaScript errors?

Comment: Uh... "Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined"

Comment: Imported it into a separate script tag and set doctype. Worked. Thanks for all the tips!

Answer (score 1):

You can give every link an unique id and then use this little javascript at the end of every site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function(){
       $("#IFOFYOURLINK").addClass("active");
    });
</script>
```

EDIT:
Try to use

```
function loadBar() {
    $('#bar').load("navigation.html", setActive);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that should be better once I get the navbar to load, as my previous code wasn't working even if I inserted the navbar manually.